# Prevent Redirect to Homepage from a other Domain holder

Tags: dns

There is a domain which i do not have access to. This domain forwards to my website. I want it to redirect to a special page on my website which informs the visitor of my page that the domain they used is not used by us but by somebody else.
Can I automatically detect the redirect and redirect it to the special website? When I do it manually the other domain owner changes it.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but this surely this will not be possible from the DNS level as you tagged the question.

You should have an HTTP handler that detects traffic coming from HTTP Referer header to again redirect to your desired site.

I would recommend filing an abuse complain if this is persistent as you said (the other owner changes it again). You can check email abuse by running a whois of the abused domain name.

Good luck handling your problem, and also the traffic which loads your server and isn't really your traffic.